# Dynamically change width of a label

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder

I have the following 4 labels arranged on a page.

```
    <s:Label id="lblName" x="10" y="13" text="{data.name}"/>
    <s:Label id="lblComputer" x="10" y="37.5"  text="{data.computer}"/>
    <s:Label id="lblModel" x="45" y="37.5"  text="{data.model}"/>
    <s:Label id="lblCPU" x="43" y="63"  text="{data.cpu}"/>
```

I'm trying to get the layout to look like this:

**lblName**

**lblComputer lblModel**

**lblCPU**

It works if lblComputer is a short name, but if it has a lot of characters, then lblComputer and lblModel run together and are totally unreadable.

Is there a way to change the x-value of lblModel dynamically to "make room" for lblComputer if lblComputer happens to be really long?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put them in VGroup and HGroup and remove the x,y flex will handle the positioning;

```
<s:VGroup>
    <s:Label id="lblName"  text="{data.name}"/>
    <s:HGroup>
        <s:Label id="lblComputer"   text="{data.computer}"/>
        <s:Label id="lblModel"   text="{data.model}"/>
    </s:HGroup>
    <s:Label id="lblCPU"  text="{data.cpu}"/>
</s:VGroup>
```